# What is the purpose of this D-shaped ring at the base of the tongue on my hiking boots?

Tags: gear

My hiking boots have a D-shaped ring at the base of the tongue. What is the purpose of this?

[image]

I don't think the purpose is to allow you to hang the boot on a hook or something, because there is a bigger strap on the back of the boot that would allow you to do that.

[image]

Or is the D-shaped ring purely decorative?

Comment: Utility for hanging the boot depends on _how_ you want to hang it. I know people who preferentially hang their boots with the soles facing upwards and outwards to help keep the insides clean, and the loop on the back is essentially useless for that purpose.

Comment: The "bootstrap" at the back of the boot is conventionally not for hanging the boot -- it's for pulling the boot on.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is a loop for the hook on [gaiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiters). The gaiters will cover the upper foot and laces on the boot, which helps prevent snow and mud build-up on the boot as well as prevent stones/sand/etc getting into the boot itself.

The hook on the gaiters goes through this loop and keeps the gaiter in place, otherwise it will slide up the foot.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it's only purpose, because it's also common to find a  flat webbing loop there that wouldn't take a gaiter hook (even if it was the right way round, which it's not) and matches loops used for laces instead of eyelets.

Comment: @ChrisH, that sounds like an additional lacing point - a different thing in a similar place.

Comment: @TobySpeight: In fact, looking at the photo above, there seems to be such a lacing point _under_ the D ring, with the lace going through it.

Comment: @Toby I agree, but the ring could also serve as a lacing point.  The one through the webbing at the bottom of the tongue is pretty pointless as it's where the lace runs anyway.  The ring is also a little high for many gaiters - a hook on the edge (used to be universal, still common) , in that ring, would expose the bottom of the tongue to mud just where it's hard to clean off.

Comment: I can confirm this answer to be true, as that is how I hang my boots when I'm off in the mountains. There have been times when I've had to spend hours scraping mud off my boots because I hung them on the back on my campsite neighbor decided to be doing 60mph in their truck through a puddle right past my trailer with the boots hanging outside. At least this way I only have to do the bottoms.

Comment: They’re Merrell’s. It’s a gaiter ring. There’s no question.

Comment: Bob1 has the right answer. It's to attach the gaiters. If you don't have such a D-ring, you can use one of those rings to attach keys and it'll do the job. Just open the split from that ring and insert the lace inside of it. As for the strap at the back, it's primarily to help put your shoes on.

Comment: Merrell description even calls it a 'Gaiter D-Ring'